# can no longer import from ElementTree

Tags: import, pydev, elementtree, python-import, xml.etree

For some years alread I have had the following import in my code:

```
from etree.ElementTree import fromstring, parse, VERSION
```

Today I made a mistake while moving (in Eclipse/pyDev) a few unrelated sourcefiles to another folder. The folder was not a package and it cost me some cleans, rebuilds and del *.pyc-s to get them found again. That part has been solved, but now, the import above breaks with "unresoved import...". When I remove the etree-prefix, the imports are resolved, but at runtime I get

```
from ElementTree import fromstring, parse, VERSION
File "C:\Program Files\Python\EPD-7.3-2x64\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 127, in <module>
from . import ElementPath
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

What is going wrong..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have been able to.

The import normally would be `from xml.etree.ElementTree import ...`; the top-level package name is [`xml.etree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), not `etree`.

It looks as if you added the `xml.etree` package to the Python `sys.path` module search path. **Don't do that**. Remove `C:\Program Files\Python\EPD-7.3-2x64\Lib\xml\etree` from your `sys.path` (or the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable) and import from the correct top-level package name instead.

Comment: pyDev still marks it as unresolved, yet Python at runtime has no problems with it. Thanks.